# Getting an error when trying to list IdleVM's in GCP using recommender

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have around 200 projects in GCP, where i am trying to list idle VM's using Google Recommender "google.compute.instance.IdleResourceRecommender". I am iterating through all zones, and finding if there any recommendations using python, code is executing fine for some projects, lets say 20 , after which it is just printing 'items', even though the projects have VM's with recommendation. Below is the code

```
import requests
import json
import re
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("")
service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = service.projects().list()
token1 = subprocess.Popen("gcloud auth print-access-token", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
token, error = token1.communicate()
token = str(token.decode("utf-8"))
token = token.rstrip("\n")
token = token.rstrip("\r")

while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()
    for project in response.get('projects', []):
        projectid = project['projectId']
        projectname = project['name']

        headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'x-goog-user-project': projectid
        }
        get_ul = "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/"+ projectid +"/zones"
        get_ul_data = requests.get(get_ul, headers= headers)
        get_json = json.loads(get_ul_data.text)
        try:
            for zones in get_json["items"]:
                zone = zones['name']
                post_url= "https://recommender.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + projectid + "/locations/"+ zone +"/recommenders/google.compute.instance.IdleResourceRecommender/recommendations"
                post_url_data = requests.get(post_url, headers = headers)
                get_api_json = json.loads(post_url_data.text)
                try:
                    for rec in get_api_json["recommendations"]:
                        for OG in rec["content"]["operationGroups"]:
                            for OPS in OG["operations"]:
                                print(rec["description"], rec["recommenderSubtype"])
                               
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

        except KeyError as e:
            print(e)

               
    request = service.projects().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

Not sure what's happening, somehow it isn't iterating through zones and listing recommendations for some projects.

Comment: I encourage you to use Google's Python SDKs for the Compute and Recommender services as you're doing for Cloud Resource Manager. As you're discovering, it's subprocess is problematic and debugging is challenging.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your concern correctly that you were getting empty from this part

```
for zones in get_json["items"]:
  zone = zones['name']
```

I think you don't need to call [Method: zones.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zones/list) to get all of the zone every time. You could just use the array to store all and get from array.

Comment: I did try that, working fine for some projects, then after it is just throwing 401, request has invalid authentication credentials.. so I validated the same project that is throwing 401 separately, it is working , no errors regarding authentication. Not sure what’s happening…

Comment: 401 is a request not authenticated due to a missing, invalid, or expired OAuth token.
Could you check that you get all proper permission for your projects? Or is the OAuth token expired? How long were you running your code?

Comment: It is quite taking time , as it iterates through all zones nd then search for recommendations. I have around 500+projects..

Comment: How about getting a new token as soon as you finish one project. I search all of the documentation, also check out the quota and limits of the recommender, I don' think that you exceed it.